# Average over specific number of rows, according to criteria

Tags: r

My data is structured as follows:

```
set.seed(20)
RawData <- data.frame(Trial = c(rep(1, 10), rep(2, 10)),
                        X_Velocity = runif(20, 1, 3), 
                        Y_Velocity = runif(20, 4, 6))
```

I now wish to calculate an average for `X_Velocity` and `Y_Velocity` across every two rows, for each `Trial`. My anticipated output, for the first four rows would be:

```
X_Velocity_AVG       Y_Velocity_AVG
NA                   NA
2.6460545            4.522224
NA                   NA
1.8081265            4.5175165
```

How do I complete this?

Comment: This is not reproducible if you don't use `set.seed()` because `rnorm` generates new random values each time. Just put `set.seed(1)` before the `data <- ...` line and then change your anticipated output

Comment: Define 'across every two rows'? Your output does not match any average - the `-0.626438` is the first row's `respose1` (from given seed).

Comment: Apologies, the question is now fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this using function `f` in which the average of every two elements is computed:

```
f <- function(a) tapply(a, rep(1:(length(a)/2), each = 2), FUN = mean)

res <- data.frame(X_Velocity_AVG=rep(NA, nrow(RawData)), 
                  Y_Velocity_AVG=rep(NA, nrow(RawData)))
res$X_Velocity_AVG[c(F,T)] <- f(RawData$X_Velocity)
res$Y_Velocity_AVG[c(F,T)] <- f(RawData$Y_Velocity)

   # X_Velocity_AVG Y_Velocity_AVG
# 1              NA             NA
# 2        2.646055       4.522224
# 3              NA             NA
# 4        1.808127       4.517517
# 5              NA             NA
# 6        2.943262       4.334551
# 7              NA             NA
# 8        1.162082       5.899396
# 9              NA             NA
# 10       1.697668       4.739195
# 11             NA             NA
# 12       2.473324       4.778723
# 13             NA             NA
# 14       1.744730       5.020097
# 15             NA             NA
# 16       1.644518       4.986245
# 17             NA             NA
# 18       1.431219       5.375815
# 19             NA             NA
# 20       2.108719       4.909284
```